# How to create new tags with Select2 AND save to database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2-4

So, I'm having a real hard time with Select2. I want users to be able to search through a select list and also create new tags when no search result is found. Creating new tags is not the problem. The main thing - and surprisingly overlooked in most forums - is to INSERT the news tags to the Database. I'm new to Select2, so I'd like to have a full example. And I'm using PHP on this project, so, if there is a way to do this with PHP it would be really helpful.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#caracteristicas').select2({theme:'bootstrap', width:null, placeholder:'Selecione', allowClear:true})
```

```html
<?php 
$q = mysqli_query($con, "select id, descricao from caracteristicas");
if(mysqli_num_rows($q)>(0))
{
?>
<div class="form-group">  
 <label for="caracteristicas">Selecione um  ou mais resultados</label>
 <select name="caracteristicas[]" id="caracteristicas" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <?php                    
  while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($q)):
  ?>
  <option value="<?=$linhas["id"]?>">
          <?=strlen($linhas["descricao"])>50 ? substr($linhas["descricao"], 0, 50)."..." : $linhas["descricao"]?>
        </option>
  <?php endwhile;?>
 </select>
</div>
<?php } mysqli_close($con);?>
```

Note: I'm using Select2 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out how to do this. I've noticed that tags created by user don't have an id, wich means, the option value will be a string, instead of a number. So, all I had to do was tell PHP to handle string values in a different way. Here's how I solved this:

```html
for($i=0; $i<count($opcoes); $i++)
{
 if(!is_numeric($opcoes[$i]))
 {
  if(!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `atividades`(`id`, `descricao`) VALUES (NULL, '".$opcoes[$i]."')"))
  {
   $msg_caracteristicas[$i] = "A atividade n&atilde;o foi cadastrada, <strong>erro <a href='http://randomurl.com' target='_blank'>#".mysqli_errno($con)."</a></strong> - \"".mysqli_error($con)."\""; 
  }
  else
  {
   echo "<script>alert('deu certo');</script>"; 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I upped voted for the concept. I'm using a different coding language so I cannot comment as to whether the PHP code provided as the answer works or not.

Comment: I think there will be an error if user put number instead of string